# Usage of "See" Phrases

Tags: meaning, usage

Does "see" have these usage forms?

1. see [noun] [noun denoting action]
   --"the plan will ***see facility renovations***"
2. see [noun] [verb in participle form]
   --"the plan will ***see facilities upgraded***"
3. see [noun] [verb in to-less infinitive form]
   --"the plan will ***see buildings transform*** into world-class facilities"
4. see [noun] [verb in gerund form]
   --"the plan will ***see buildings transforming*** into world-class facilities"

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Plan 1 = "There will be facility renovations."
Plan 2 = "The facilities will be upgraded."
Plan 3 = "Buildings will be transformed into world-class facilities."
Plan 4 = "Buildings will begin their transformation into world-class facilities."

In general, "The plan will see `whatever the plan states`."

Your choice of verb tense may depend on what perspective you want to take.