# The usage of "see"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, grammaticality, usage, register

Are the following sentences grammatical?

> The summer of 2000 saw me in a research project at a museum in Africa.
>
> The summer of 2000 saw me doing a research project at a museum in Africa.

The verb "see" has a definition "*Be the time or setting of (something)*", according to the ODO. So is the above usage correct?

Since the ODO definition says "time or setting", does the subject of "see" in this sense have to be a time or time period? All the example sentences I have seen seem to point to that.

However, just came across this question:
[Usage of "See" Phrases](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/usage-of-see-phrases)

Also I have found several instances where the subject of "see" is neither time or a sentient being. Do these fall under the same usage? Are these instances grammatical?

> The project, dubbed the "Holiday Hole," saw online donors contribute more than $100,573 -- or, as organizers called it, "money thrown in the hole" -- for the frivolous dig. (source: [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2016/11/28/us/holiday-hole-cards-against-humanity-black-friday-trnd/index.html))
>
> Part-commentary on the way we live today and part-experiment, the project saw stacks of books accompanied only by a simple note that encouraged passers-by to take a book for free, read it and on completing the book, email me. ([source](http://www.madebysherry.com/readingproject/))
>
> Different stages of the project saw dramatic shift of winds, particularly when it came to conflict areas. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=U7meBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22the%20project%20saw%22&source=bl&ots=yoQspe4l3m&sig=kgIotcwgKZ5vwvoYe9eDyT15FWY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJq8H7gZDaAhXndN8KHS8aC8QQ6AEIbjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20project%20saw%22&f=false))

Comment: Grammatical, yes, but more than a little strange. You're treating your activity or involvement in the project as an *event* that took place or a *development* that happened during the specified time frame.  **The 18th century saw an explosion in the number of London banks**. **The 18th century saw the establishment of physiology as an individual discipline.**  The phrase **of something** in the ODO's definition is misleading in its generality.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Does the subject of "see" in this sense have to be a time or time period? All the example sentences I have seen seem to point to that.

Comment: Yes, it must be a reference to a time period.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo As I was trying to see if a similar question has been answered, I came across this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/usage-of-see-phrases  Now I am confused again...

Comment: I disagree with that answer.

Comment: Can you find a single attestation in which a native speaker writes "the plan will see"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I found some similar instances. I am editing it into the question.

Comment: Days, months, years, seasons and periods are frequently personified as the subjects of such verbs as **see, witness and observe**. Shakespeare: Romeo & Juliet: *The grey-ey'd morn smiles on the frowning night...*

Answer (score 1):

On a semantic level, I would paraphrase this construction:

`The {time-setting} saw  {noteworthy event or development}`

as

{noteworthy event or development} *happened or came to pass during* {time-setting}.

The subject of **see** with this meaning must be understandable as a time-span or as happening over a time-span. Nouns like **undertaking** and **project**, insofar as they refer to a duration, are acceptable.

The age saw... the millennium saw... The 1930s saw .... The undertaking saw.... The project saw .... The development saw ... The voyage saw... The mission saw ... The semester saw ... The season saw ... The inning saw ... The game saw .... The tournament saw ... etc etc

We would not say:

> The **ship** saw acts of great bravery.

because **ship** does not refer to or have a duration.

But we could say

> The **battle** saw acts of great bravery.

because a battle does have duration.

The register of this construction  is somewhat "heightened" and it is not typically used with the Quotidien but with the  Noteworthy. It is a synonym for the verb **witnessed**.

We wouldn't say

> The afternoon saw little Johnny  skin his knee, play a game of hide-and-go-seek, and then enjoy a snack of peanut butter and crackers.

not unless we were striving to be humorously mock-heroic, raising these minor events in the life of a child to a level they do not usually occupy.

In the same way

> The summer of 2000 saw me in a research project at a museum in Africa.

could sound rather grandiloquent.  It's not ungrammatical, but unless the statement is part of a narrative, it would sound odd. It does not state the fact neutrally.

Comment: Sometimes metonymy can be a problem as in “the ship saw bravery”

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "can be a problem".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I'm not sure what that means, either, but I will say this: it was originally posted as an answer. After it got flagged, I converted it to a comment. It just seemed like the comment might be better under your answer than under the question itself.